# Lodash orderBy based on property child count

Tags: javascript, lodash

I would like to count objects of property and orderBy considering the count result.

```
 var users = [
            { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
            { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 }
        ];

// Sort by `user` in ascending order and by `age` in descending order.
        _.orderBy(users, ['user', 'age'], ['asc', 'desc']);
```

From the doc, this work but what I want is to have something like :

```
var users = [
            { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 ,Likes: [{objAA},{objBA}]},
            { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 ,Likes: [{objBA},{objBB},{objBC}]},
            { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 ,Likes: [{objDA},{objDA}]},
            { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 ,Likes: [{objCA}]}
        ];
```

orderBy Likes count

```
var users = [
            { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 ,Likes: [{objBA},{objBB},{objBC}]},
            { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 ,Likes: [{objAA},{objBA}]},
            { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 ,Likes: [{objDA},{objDA}]},
            { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 ,Likes: [{objCA}]}
        ];
```

Is this possible using loadh only ?

What I need is something like

```
_.orderBy(users, ['user.Likes.length'], ['desc']);
_.orderBy(users, ['user.Likes'], ['desc']);
```

But above code doesn't work but no errors

I would like to use orderBy function to be able after to combine the ordering like

```
_.orderBy(users, ['user.Likes','user', 'age'], ['desc','asc', 'desc']);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you may use function iterators like this

```
 _.orderBy(users, ['user', function (o) {
    return o.likes.length;
 }], ["asc", "asc"])
```

here's an example

```js
var users = [{
  'user': 'fred',
  'age': 48,
  'likes': [{c:1}, {c:2}, {c:3}]
}, {
  'user': 'barney',
  'age': 34,
  'likes': [{c:1}, {c:2}, {c:3}, {c:3}]
}, {
  'user': 'ammar',
  'age': 25,
  'likes': [{c:1}, {c:2}, {c:3}, {c:3}, {c:1}, {c:2}, {c:3}]
}, {
  'user': 'boston',
  'age': 34,
  'likes': [{c:1}, {c:3}]
}, {
  'user': 'obama',
  'age': 34,
  'likes': [{c:1}]
}, {
  'user': 'barney',
  'age': 34,
  'likes': [{c:1}, {c:2}, {c:3}]
}];


document.write(JSON.stringify(_.orderBy(users, ['user', function (o) {
  return o.likes.length;
}], ["asc", "asc"]), null, 4))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.6.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a function as the iteratee:

```
_.orderBy(users, user => user.Likes.length, ['desc']);
```